# Key Error from Lambda when Querying DynamoDB

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the following Lamdba function to query Dynamo DB:

```
import json
import boto3 

from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

#always start with the lambda_handler
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    lessonVar = event["lessonVar"]
    courseVar = event["courseVar"]
    # make the connection to dynamodb
    dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb") 
    # select the table
    table = dynamodb.Table("test")
    response = table.get_item(Key={
        "coursename" : "courseVar",
        "lesson": lessonVar
    })
    return response['Item']
```

here are my table details:

```
Primary partition key:  coursename (String)
Primary sort key:   lesson (Number)
```

I keep getting a key error on line 8 as follows:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'lessonVar'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 8, in lambda_handler\n    lessonVar = event[\"lessonVar\"]\n"
  ]
}
```

I am using the following test criteria:

```
{
  "coursename": "introto",
  "lesson": 1
}
```

Does anyone see anything I missed? I need another set of eyes as Im at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that `lessonVar` is not a valid lookup key on `event`. Your test data does not contain a property named `lessonVar`. Your code should be something like the following:

```
lessonVar = event["lesson"]
courseVar = event["coursename"]
```